# SSRS 2016 Chart not loading in Chrome

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I'm using SSRS 2016 Reporting services.  I created a line chart and when i view the report through the application (report viewer control) it is working fine in IE but the chart is not loading in chrome. Once I refreshed the URL using ctrl+F5 it is loading. But close the viewer controller and open it again it will not load.

Can any one help.... ?